# R package to generate simple GUI from r script, comparable to pywebio in python

Tags: python, r, shiny

Are you aware of any r package that would easily convert a working script into web app? Shiny of course does that but it is a bit complicated for simple tasks particularly with all these reactive functions we have to add. I recently cane across pywebio in python where you can make very minimal changes to the python script then you end up with a functioning webapp.
Is there a similar package in r?
Or is there an easy way to change r script into shiny by modifying the input and output code only?

I did my search and couldn’t find something that does the job. There are a few shiny packages that help design the user interface but the server side part will remain a bit complicated.

Comment: "script into web app" is generally `shiny` or perhaps plotly's `dash`. There is no wrapper that takes arbitrary code and web-app-izes it, not sure how that would look, considering every app is different, both in interface expectations and the processing done with the bespoke code.

Answer (score 0):

Shinydashboard:
Purpose: Simplified framework on top of Shiny.
Use Case: Ideal for creating dashboards.
Features: Provides a structured layout with a sidebar and body.
Note: Still built on Shiny, but reduces reactive programming complexity.

Flexdashboard:
Purpose: Creates dashboards using R Markdown.
User-Friendly: Requires less code compared to traditional Shiny apps.
Note: Uses R Markdown, making it more accessible and straightforward.

{shinymeta}:
Purpose: Simplifies Shiny app creation.
Approach: Allows app layout description in a simple configuration file.
Note: Designed to streamline Shiny app development.